# getting errors while installing ISV licence using AXUpdateInstaller.exe devinstall for D365FO

Tags: installation, microsoft-dynamics, x++

while trying to install the ISV package using AXUpdateInstaller.exe devinstall I have updated the name of the machine in the default topology data file but when i m running the install command(AXUpdateInstaller.exe devinstall) it is taking the machine name as localhost resulting in falilure of the installation. How to rectify this ?

I have tried the same steps again but they havent worked.